# prove in set theory and function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function and $S\subset X,T\subset Y$ be subsets of the domain and range respectively.

I would like to prove that $f(S)\cap T= f(S\cap f^{-1}(T))$

Proof:
Starting from the left inclusion:

Let and arbitrary $x\in f(S)\cap T \implies x \in f(S) \land x \in T$

$\implies f^{-1}(x) \in S \land f^{-1}(x) \in T $

$f^{-1}(x) \in S \cap T \implies x\in f( S \cap f^{-1} T)$

Can I really just do this to finish this part of the proof? Is it legit to do like this, and do i need to do the other inclusion or is it the exact same just read the passages from below?

Comment: It's a bad idea to write "$x\in f(S)\cap T) \implies x \in f(S) \land x\in T$" when you don't yet know that. That is what you are trying to show, so label it as "we are trying to show" or something like that. Also, I don't know what you mean by $f(x)\in Y : x \in S \land X \in T$.  I guess you mean $x \in S$ and $f(x) \in T$?

Comment: @JennyKenkel am i writing wrong the definition of image? How should i write then for example $x\in f(A)$ with $A\subset X$?

Comment: If you want to write $x \in f(A)$ and $A \subset X$, that's exactly how you write it. But above you wrote that $x \in S$ and $X \in T$. I don't know if you mean that $X \subseteq T$? Or $x \in T$? Or $f(x) \in T$?

Comment: Oh I see, I was wrong with my first comment, writing "$x\in f(S)\cap T) \implies x \in f(S) \land x\in T$" is fine

Comment: However, if you assume that $x\in f(S)\cap T) \implies x \in f(S) \land x\in T$, then you are assuming that $x \in Y$. The next line, though, you say $f(x) \in Y$. So you are using $x$ to play two different roles.

Comment: I'm Just getting confused with this comments so I'll say something here to clear things out, first of all I think that $f(S):=${$f(x) \in Y| x \in S$} therefore if I need to say that $x \in f(S)$ I would say that $ \exists b \in S s.t b= f(x)$ is that wrong?

Comment: To show $x \in f(S)$, you need to show that there exists a $b \in S$ such that $x=f(b)$. 

It may help to use different letters when you are defining $f(S)$; I think you got thrown off by the fact that you were using $x$ there as well.

Comment: @JennyKenkel I need to find b? Doesn't it exist always for definition?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you sort things out.  I think that both better notation and less logical symbolism (i.e. more words) will help here. Also note that this is akin to a diagram chase for those who are familiar, meaning just follow the definitions and not a lot of insight needed. But that doesn't mean you shouldn't work through it when learning. Note that you are trying to prove something happening in the set $Y$ so even the small change of using $y$ (or $t$) not $x$ to start will make this easier. This was already noted in the comments.

We need to show:

(1) $f(S)\cap T \subseteq f(S\cap f^{-1}(T))$
(2) $f(S\cap f^{-1}(T)) \subseteq f(S)\cap T$

For (1):

Let $y\in f(S)\cap T$. Then $y\in f(S)$ and $y\in T$. Therefore $y=f(s)$ for some $s\in S$ and $s\in f^{-1}(T)$ since $y\in T$. Therefore $s\in S\cap f^{-1}(T)$ and $y=f(s)\in f(S\cap f^{-1}(T))$.

For (2):

Let $y\in f(S\cap f^{-1}(T))$. Then $y=f(s)$ for some $s\in S\cap f^{-1}(T)$. Since $s\in S$, $y\in f(S)$ and since $s\in f^{-1}(T)$, $y\in T$. Therefore $y\in f(S)\cap  T$.